# QML examples doesn’t run on Windows CE

Tags: qt, windows-ce, qml

I built the Qt 4.8.4 examples targeting Windows CE ARM4I platform, everything works well except those examples including QML. They just don’t run without error message and I couldn’t figure out what is the cause of the problem. Has anyone encountered the same problem and got a solution?

Though it’s not essential for me to use QML in my development, I still want to fugure it out.

Regards,
Xuan

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It’s dll problem. Some QML examples need sql, network or other dlls to run.